# How to use bootstrap nav-tabs in angular 4 as parent child components?

Tags: angular

My code looks like this i want to use this as parent component and all others tabs are child component. i want to pass parent components data to all child components how can i achieve it pls help

```
<section class="section_custom">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="card card-nav-tabs">
      <div class="card-header card-header-white">
        <div class="nav-tabs-navigation">
          <div class="nav-tabs-wrapper pull-right">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" href="#details" data-toggle="tab">Candidate Details</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a [class]="id==null ?'nav-link disabled':'nav-link'" href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Public Profile</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a [class]="id==null ?'nav-link disabled':'nav-link'" href="#login" data-toggle="tab">Account Settings</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a [class]="id==null ?'nav-link disabled':'nav-link'" href="#videos" data-toggle="tab">Videos</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="tab-content">
          <div class="tab-pane active" id="details">
            <app-candidate-edit></app-candidate-edit>
          </div>
          <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">
            <app-candidate-profile></app-candidate-profile>
          </div>
          <div class="tab-pane" id="login">
            <app-candidate-login></app-candidate-login>
          </div>
          <div class="tab-pane" id="videos">
            <app-candidate-video-list></app-candidate-video-list>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Would be nice to have some more info. What data and to what child component. Because now I can only think of this.
     `<app-chat [comments]="comments" [itemId]="itemId"></app-chat>`
In parent
     `itemId: number;
      comments: Array<{}>;`

In app-chat
    `<div 
     *ngIf="comments"
     class="chatContainer"
     [style.display]="displayChat"
     >
     <!--Some more code-->
     </div>`

Have a look in here it is helpfull
https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction
How to pass data from parent to child